# How to include headefile and functions at runtime C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries, googletest

I two base projects. `Proj1.lib` and `Proj2.exe`. Now `Proj2.exe` is the startup projects and it will invoke `Proj1.lib`. Now when i will add another `Test.lib` to my main project, which contains `Gtest`. Now, to make `Gtest` to accumulate all the test cases in `GTest`, we need to call a function from `Test.lib` and that function name and header file need to be included in `Proj2.exe`. Then `Proj.exe` will get compiled and then it will compile `Test.lib` and then it will execute test cases. But now my requiremnet is not to disturb `Proj2.exe`. When ever I want I will attach/deach`Test.lib` or `Test2.lib` ... and so on.

Below will show, how we are doing it currently.

`Proj1.lib`

```
x.c file
y.c file {/*App_Main_function()*/}
```

`Proj2.exe`

```
A.cpp
B.cpp file {/*Call App_Main_function();*/}
AttachTest.cpp {Test_Main();}
```

`Test.lib`

```
Test.cpp
{
    TestMain()
    {/*Body*/
        InitilizeGoogleTest();
        TEST_F(abc, ab)
        {}
    }
}
```

Tomorrow if there will be more or new test libraries then I have to open `AttachTest.cpp` file from `Proj.exe` and add the function name and header files name. Then Proj2.exe will compile again.

But I want now I will keep `Proj1.lib` and `Proj2.exe` fix they won't get compile except new `Test.lib`
How to do that,

I have thought of a way to do it as, I will have `.xml` file, which will have function name. In `Proj2.exe`, I will have function pointers it will call them at run time. But how to include header file then??

Please help me.

Comment: You need to use DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build Dynamic-Link libraries (DLL) for doing what you want. `.lib` libraries can't be loaded dynamically.

Below some example code how to use such libraries, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// DLL function signature
typedef double (*importFunction)(double, double);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        importFunction addNumbers;
        double result;
        HINSTANCE hinstLib;

        // Load DLL file
        hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Example.dll"));
        if (hinstLib == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to load DLL\n");
                return 1;
        }

        // Get function pointer
        addNumbers = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "AddNumbers");
        if (addNumbers == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to find DLL function\n");
                FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                return 1;
        }

        // Call function.
        result = addNumbers(1, 2);

        // Unload DLL file
        FreeLibrary(hinstLib);

        // Display result
        printf("The result was: %f\n", result);

        return 0;
}
```